# Alternatives to xml by developing android app layout?

Tags: android, xml, layout

I would like to know if there is some other alternative or propper way for developing the UI of an android app. I know that XML is used, and also why - but are there any other methods even if they are not very efficient?

Comment: The main advantages of using XML layout are separation of UI and code and easy support for unknown screen sizes.  Why would you give those up?

Comment: You can achieve the same thing without XML. XML is too rigid for my liking.

Comment: Another reason I like to use JSON is its easier for UI artists to be put in charge of  JSON file than to have them dig into the XML themselves.

Answer (score 9):

You are welcome to create your UI by creating Java objects directly and stitching them together into their parent-child relationships, including the layout managers needed to control things like sizing and positioning.

And, given that, you are welcome to invent your own means of defining an UI (parse some JSON, use a random number generator, etc.), as in the end it is all just Java objects.

Comment: This is what I did for iOS and what I'm going to do for Android. I create an 'AutoLayout' java class that parses a JSON object. e.g `["type":"button","x"20,"below":"topBar","buttonText":"This is a button"]` etc.

Answer (score 3):

If you are developing games, there are some game frameworks like Cocos2d-x or Unity that have their own ways to display content on the screen. They can also be useful for apps that require some kind of 3D visualization (Unity for example can embedded in a native app).

Other than that, the alternative to XML is to create views programatically in Java, and manage the view hierarchy by yourself. You can mix both, which is especially useful when you want to create content dynamically based on some data you fetch at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

One framework that seems promising, is [Flutter](https://flutter.dev/). You need to know [Dart language](https://dart.dev/), however, it's easy to catch.
BTW, Flutter is a cross platform framework and you can use it for both Android and iOS development.

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with native Android UI layout and design